# Upload Image from React Native using react-native-image-picker to Amazon S3 with presigned url

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, image-upload

I need help on my case.
I am using react-native-image-picker to pick image, current problem are when need to upload the image.

I prepare presignedurl

```
//here I get the presigned url
  const uploadConfig = await profileApi.getUpdateUrl(id); 
  //I prepare file from response of imagepicker : uri , filename , file type, data(base64 file)
  const file = {
    uri: values.Avatar.uri,
    name: values.Avatar.fileName,
    type: values.Avatar.type,
    data: value.Avatar.data,
  }; 

  //upload to presignedurl of S3 , already tried file.data , file.uri respectively but it resulted same
  const resultUpload = await axios.put(uploadConfig.data.url, file, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': file.type,
    },
  });
```

The result is accepted with no error, but it resulted blank image which when I download is not a image.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use axios instead use XMLHttpRequest, I don't know why but this worked:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('PUT', presignedUrl)
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('Image successfully uploaded to S3')
        } else {
            console.log('Error while sending the image to S3')
        }
    }
}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', response.type)
xhr.send({uri: response.uri, type: response.type, name: response.filename})
```

Comment: Oh my, you saved my day! But I was using axios and it was sending an JSON instead of a file. I tried this and it worked for me. But still, why is axios not working?

Comment: Hi, happy to hear that was helped you, and I really don't know why but I think it's related to FormData check [this](https://medium.com/@istvanistvan/react-native-file-uploads-with-axios-and-redux-thunk-73d8093d7243)